# What is the definition of climate realism

Tags: meaning, terminology

What is the definition of climate realism? I have to explain it to my friend as she claims that there is no definition of it in turkish, I searched it up and did not see a clear definition so I have wanted to ask it. I AM DETERMINED TO GET IT

Comment: Benny Peiser: What Is Climate Realism? https://www.thegwpf.org/benny-peiser-what-is-climate-realism/

Comment: As you can see that my english is not very good, can u sum it up for me? I do not really think that I am able to read it

Comment: Can you paste the text into [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/)?

Comment: Translate would not do it correct

Comment: All you need to read is "Climate realism acknowledges the significant difference between verifiable and replicable knowledge, and hypothetical knowledge based on indirect evidence." - try Google Translate.

Comment: It looks like a philosophical position regarding the climate change debate. Instead of blindly siding with climate activists or those denying climate change, and instead of using just anecdotal or local events to justify their position (e.g. “Australia had massive bushfires, so global warming must be true”), it requires sufficiently-extensive data as well as an examination of the data model and the quality of the data itself. It also requires an examination of the mechanisms claimed to be the cause of climate change, down to whatever granularity is needed to be scientifically convincing.

Comment: If my previous comment accurately portrays the position, the “realist” part relates to the question, “What is _really_ happening to the climate?” It contrasts reality with both mere conjecture or (limited) personal experience, and with hype.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your friend should attend the lecture, but the summary in your link

> Climate realism acknowledges the significant difference between verifiable and replicable knowledge, and hypothetical knowledge based on indirect evidence.

means that there are broadly two sources of information:

1. Experiment and measurement, which can be repeated and checked by climate scientists.
2. Theory and supposition based on argument, opinion, discussion, and inference.

**Climate realism** recognises the gap between the two approaches, and attempts to discover the most useful conclusions that can be drawn about climate change.